# How to show data as notification from database in html/php header bar in notification icon

Tags: php, android, html, mysql

I have a table name **order_detail** in MySQL database and I get values in it from my android app so I want to show order_id as a notification in my admin panel which is coded in HTML/PHP

**Table Name: order_detail** its attributes are as follow

**item_id** | **order_id** | **item_name** | **price** |  **quantity**

I have notification icon in my admin panel I want to show order_id in it whenever someone gives order from android app and that order is stored in above-mentioned table I get notification

code for notification icon is:

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="label label-pill label-danger count" style="border-radius:10px;"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="font-size:18px;"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to do so. I'll demonstrate 2 ways one for beginner and the other is way more advanced.

1- Create a **PHP** function that gets user notifications from the database and call it using **ajax** and `setInterval()` js function to automatically call the server-side function every certain period of time (ex: 10 seconds) Example code:

**Javascript**

```
function getUserNotifications() {
    //Call server here and get notifications
    //Then modify notifications list in HTML.
}

//Then use the setInterval function on document ready
setInterval(getUserNotifications, 10000); //10000 = 10 seconds
```

2- Get to learn about **WebPush** and the numerous packages out there that can get real-time notifications sent from server to client. 
Example packages for PHP: [Github: Web push php](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php) and [Stackoverflow: How to use web push php library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474960/web-push-notification-how-to-use-web-push-php-library) and finally a [Github web push example project](https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example)

Enjoy learning.