# Web Push php libriary : Throws internal error

Tags: php, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-push

I used the web push library to send push notifications
https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php

I getting an internal error while trying to sen push notification

I checked in both PHP version:7.1.22,7.2.9-1
Apache error log throws :

> [:error][client ::1:33302] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected
>   '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /PWA/web-push-php-example/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/Subscription.php
>   on line 41, referer: http://localhost/PWA/web-push-php-example/src/

And i also tried in Ngnix / error log :

> 17:22:36 [error] 20232#20232: *46 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: endpoint in
>   /var/www/html/PWA/web-push-php-example/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/Subscription.php
>   on line 69 PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument
>   1 passed to Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription::__construct() must be of
>   the type string, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/PWA/web-push-php-example/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/Subscription.php
>   on line 72 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/PWA/web-push-php-example/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/Subscription.php:39
>   Stack trace:   thrown in
>   /var/www/html/PWA/web-push-php-example/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/Subscription.php
>   on line 39" while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   127.0.0.1, server: local.pwa.com, request: "POST /PWA/web-push-php-example/src/send_push_notification.php HTTP/2.0",
>   upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "localhost", referrer:
>   "https://localhost/PWA/web-push-php-example/src/"

PHP code :

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
use Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription;

// here I'll get the subscription endpoint in the POST parameters
// but in reality, you'll get this information in your database
// because you already stored it (cf. push_subscription.php)
$sub =json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$sub_endpoint =$sub['endpoint'];
$sub_publicKey =$sub['publicKey'];
$sub_authToken =$sub['authToken'];
$sub_contentEncoding =$sub['contentEncoding'];
$notifications = [
    [
        'subscription' => Subscription::create([            
            'endPoint' => $sub_endpoint,
            'publicKey' => $sub_publicKey,            
            'authToken' => $sub_authToken,            
            'contentEncoding' => $sub_contentEncoding, // one of PushManager.supportedContentEncodings
        ]),
        'payload' => '{msg:"test"}',
    ],
];

$auth = array(
    'VAPID' => array(
        'subject' => 'mailto:me@website.com', // can be a mailto: or your website address
        'publicKey' => 'BCmti7ScwxxVAlB7WAyxoOXtV7J8vVCXwEDIFXjKvD-ma-yJx_eHJLdADyyzzTKRGb395bSAtxlh4wuDycO3Ih4', // (recommended) uncompressed public key P-256 encoded in Base64-URL
        'privateKey' => 'HJ*******************' // (recommended) in fact the secret multiplier of the private key encoded in Base64-URL
        //'pemFile' => './keys/private_key.pem' // if you have a PEM file and can link to it on your filesystem        
    ),
);
$defaultOptions = array(
    'TTL' => 300, // defaults to 4 weeks
    'urgency' => 'normal', // protocol defaults to "normal"
    'topic' => 'push', // not defined by default - collapse_key
);

$webPush = new WebPush($auth, $defaultOptions);

// send multiple notifications with payload

$webPush->flush();

// send one notification and flush directly
$webPush->sendNotification(
    $notifications[0]['subscription'],
    $notifications[0]['payload'], // optional (defaults null)
    true // optional (defaults false)
);
```

Comment: Here's the problems https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php/blob/master/src/Subscription.php#L41-L43. I must say I've never seen a `__construct()` with arguments starting with `?` before. What's that about? Incidentally, the Travis build of that package is failing, are you sure it actually works properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web Push Notification: How to use Web Push PHP Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44474960/web-push-notification-how-to-use-web-push-php-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harish, Constructor '?' should work from PHP version 7.1. I find there is a mistake in your parameter values.

**__construct() must be of the type string, null given, called in /var/www/html/PWA/web-push-php-example/vendor/minishlink/web-push/src/Subscription.php**

As the error log indicates the endpoint value is passed as null, it should be passed as string value.

The variable your passing in the notification as **endPoint** but in lib it assigned as **endpoint**.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure you are actually running PHP 7.21 or 7.2? The problem is the question marks in the constructor here:

https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php/blob/master/src/Subscription.php#L41-L43

As you can see from this 3v4l code, it works on all versions over 7.1:

```
<?php
class X
{
    public function __construct(
        string $endpoint,
        ?string $publicKey = null,
        ?string $authToken = null,
        ?string $contentEncoding = null
    ) {
        $this->endpoint = $endpoint;

    }
}

$x = new X('blah', 'blahblah');
```

https://3v4l.org/A1XeN

All v5 iterations of the code produce your error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /in/A1XeN on line 6
```

Comment: This my php version :
PHP 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Aug 19 2018 07:16:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: This is my another php version i tried : PHP 7.1.22 (cli) (built: Sep 12 2018 07:22:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.22, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies